# Java 8: Filtering Map<Long, Person> to List<Long> by person's status

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to filter a `Map<Long, Person> people` and return only the IDs of these people having a status of `SUBSCRIBED` in a `List<Long>`. Here is the code in the old-fashioned way:

```
public List<Long> getSubscribedPeople() {
    final List<Long> subscribedPeople = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final Map.Entry<Long, Person> entry : subscribedPeople.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().getStatus() == PersonStatus.SUBSCRIBED) {
            subscribedPeople.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    return subscribedPeople;
}
```

The Person class looks as follows:

```
class Person {
    private Long id;
    private PersonStatus status;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I tried the following, but this only gives me a `List<Entry<Long, Person>>`:

```
public List<Long> getSubscribedPeople() {
    return people.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(e -> e.getValue().getStatus() == PersonStatus.SUBSCRIBED)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Do I have to `map` the stream somehow?

Comment: Yes add `.map(e -> e.getKey())` before you collect.

Comment: You may also consider returning a `long[]` array instead: `.mapToLong(Map.Entry::getKey).toArray()`…

Comment: If the keys correspond to `Person.id`, you could work with the values only: this will avoid the need to manipulate the `Map.Entry`'s: `people.values().stream().filter(p -> p.getStatus() == SUBSCRIBED).map(p -> p.getId()).collect(toList())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before collecting, map the stream of entries to its keys. Otherwise you will have a stream of entries.

```
public List<Long> getSubscribedPeople() {
    return people.entrySet() // set of entries 
        .stream() // stream of entries
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().getStatus() == PersonStatus.SUBSCRIBED) // stream of entries 
        .map(e -> e.getKey()) // stream of longs
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // list of longs
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i did now. I just edited the example above and changed the comparision to ==.